# How does UIScreen.main.nativeBounds relate to x and y coordinates?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, uiscreen

If I `print` `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height` it returns `2048` for my iPad simulator which is fine. But how does this relate to the `x and y coordinates`? For example, the middle of the screen is `x: 0, y: 0`. And if I move to the left on the `x coordinates` I use minus, like `x: -100`, and if I move to the right I use plus, like `x: 100`.

In my head this would mean that `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height` is divided by 2 so that I can move between `x: -1024` and `x: 1024`. Is that correct? Well, it seems that it's not because this code:

```
portrait = gui.addPortrait(width: 80, height: 80, x:-350 , y:  180)
addChild(portrait)
```

will take me to the far end of the device's x-axis, like this:

[image]

meaning that the total `x-axis` must be something like 750 in total. What happened to 1024? I think I must misunderstand how the `x-coordinates` relate to the `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height`. The reason I want to understand this is because I want to set the `x position` dynamically so that it works on all devices. Something like `x: -(UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height / 3)`. What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using SpriteKit, I would recommend not even bothering with UIScreen unless you need it.

Comment: If not using UIScreen, how will I position objects like text and images at certain positions?

Comment: You have a scene, you should be working in scene coordinates.  Use the view attached to it so that you can tell you the aspect ratio. Or better yet, translate the 4 corners from view to scene with `convertPoint(fromView point:CGPoint)` so you know your bounding rect in your scene

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to `UIScreen.bounds`, which specifies "[t]he bounding rectangle of the screen, measured in points" ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds)), `UIScreen.nativeBounds` specifies "[t]he bounding rectangle of the physical screen, measured in pixels" ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617810-nativebounds)).

Thus, you'll want to transform the values into points with the help of [`UIScreen.nativeScale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617825-nativescale):

```swift
let width = round(UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width / UIScreen.main.nativeScale)
let height = round(UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height / UIScreen.main.nativeScale)
```

Comment: Does that give me the the maxX or something similar? Width gave me 768.0 and self.frame.maxX gave me 375.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height and width of the screen in points like this:

```
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

No point of the screen has negative coordinates:

The top left-hand corner of the screen is `x: 0, y :0`

The top right-hand corner of the screen is `x: width, y: 0`

The bottom left-hand corner of the screen is `x: 0, y: height`

The bottom right-hand corner of the screen is `x: width, y: height`

Comment: No negative coordinates? If I set x: 0 the image is set to the middle of the screen. If I use negative values it alignes to the left. If I use positive values it aligns to the right... Not saying you are wrong, but why do I get this result?

Comment: What hat is "gui" in your example? What are its dimensions?

Comment: Its an SKScene. And addPortrait returns an SKShapeNode. Dimensions of gui?

Comment: Each view has bounds (relative to itself) and frame (relative to parent) - I won't be able to help you because the code you have included is not enough to reproduce this.

Comment: What exactly do you need? Let me know and I'll post it above :)